# Replace pagination Next link to image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

[quick pagination](http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_quick_paginate/demo.html)

i have downloaded the pagination from this site, ya really fine , no script problem and nothing ,

But i tried to change the **next** link to image , but am not find success ,

actually they given the CSS name for the next and back link ,

i simply overrided using css , background image, then image has changed , but i cant able to replace this >> symbol

from the pagination ...

Any idea, How to replace the text   link to image link...

my present plugin in look like « Prev1 / 3Next » Replace to « prev image / next image »

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an anchor tag. You can place the image as an `<img />` element and remove the inner text from the anchor tag. Something like

```
<a class=""><mg src="your_image_path" alt="Previous" /></a>
```

Comment: in that plugin they given the js file, in that file they declaed the next prev link label names, i just replaced, and inserted the img tag, then i got image, but with image >> symbol also displaying